# Error with NodeJS FS (writeFile)

Tags: javascript, node.js, native, fs

Here is my piece of my router who manage my uploads :

```
fs.readFile(files.photo.path, function (err, data) {
    // Here is the futur name of my file (ex: SERVER_PATH/images/moka/moka22/11/2016_1.jpg)
    var newPath = __dirname + "/images/moka/moka" + new Date().toLocaleDateString() + "_" + Math.floor(Math.random() * 10) + 1 + "." + ext;
    fs.writeFile(newPath, data, function (err) {
      if(err) {
        res.render('error', { error: err, message: "Erreur lors de l'upload"});
      } else {
        // insctructions
        });
      }
    });
  });
```

When the code is triggered I have this error :

```
Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'D:\projects\raspberry\routes\images\moka\moka2016-11-22_91.jpg'
at Error (native)
```

If I well understood the fs doc (https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fs_fs_writefile_file_data_options_callback) :

```
fs.writeFile(theNameOfTheFuturFile, theDataToPutIn, callback);
```

So I'm a bit confused.

Sorry for my english, it may be bad, i hope that you guess what i mean :)

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem could be the directory you are writing to does not exist.

so make sure it exists:

```
fs.readFile(files.photo.path, function (err, data) {
    var dirPath = __dirname + "/images/moka/moka";
    if (!fs.existsSync(dirPath)){
        fs.mkdirSync(dirPath);
    }
    ...
```

or do it by hand.

Comment: The 1st arg of writefile was the filename. But my PathName was wrong